# Uploading a file to Supabase storage using Nextjs and formidable

Tags: next.js, supabase

I am trying to upload a file to Supabase using the Nextjs API route and formidable. Below is the code:

```
form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error', err)
                throw err
            }
            const {data, error} = await supabase 
                .storage
                .from('apg-bucket')
                .upload(files.image.originalFilename, files.image, {
                    contentType: files.image.mimetype,
                    cacheControl: '3600',
                    upsert: false,
                })
```

The problem is when the file gets uploaded into Supabase this is 0-150 bytes rather than the total size of the file (7937 bytes). See below:

[image: SupabaseImageUpload]

From logging I can see that the file is coming into the API via the form and is being captured by formidable. See below:

[image: ConsoleLogNextJS]

Wondering what I am doing wrong and the reason why the full file doesn't get uploaded into the storage bucket?

Have tried to change the file variable in the Supabase upload from:

- files.image[0]
- files.image.filepath
- files[0]

All the above did is change the byte value within Supabase to 0 - 50 bytes rather than the entire image.

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just updating this and have figured out the solution.

Solution below

```
form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error', err)
            throw err
        } else {
            console.log('Files:', files.image.filepath)

            const fileContent = await fs.promises.readFile(files.image.filepath)  //this is what was missing!

            const { data, error } = await supabase
                .storage
                .from('apg-bucket')
                .upload(files.image.originalFilename, fileContent, {
                    contentType: files.image.mimetype,
                    cacheControl: '3600',
                })
            
        }
```

Turns out the fs module was needed otherwise the file content doesn't get attached within the call.